# How do I add MongoDB Realm App Users to Atlas collection?

Tags: mongodb, swiftui, realm

I'm working on a SwiftUI app that connects to a MongoDB Atlas database (hosted) which is populated and managed by a server.  I've created a Realm for my SwiftUI app, and can sucessfully create a user and log-in, but I'm having trouble connecting the created user (found in App Users in the Realm UI) to a user document in my database's User collection.  Whats the proper way to do this? Do I need to manually create a user in the collection for any new app users?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use the SDK to read and write data - I mean, that's what it there for, right? There are great examples in the Getting Started Guide [Read & Write Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/read-and-write-data/#read---write-data---swift-sdk). Have you taken a look at that? Oh - you do NOT need to manually create users. Our apps have a user signup where the app creates the user accounts for the user. That's all done through [Authenticate](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/users/authenticate-users/#std-label-ios-authenticate-users)

Comment: One other thing; if you don't have rules (permissions) in place, any of your apps users can access any data, so there should't really be a situation where a 'connect a user to a user document'. In other words, if a user authenticates, and then the app connects to your Realm, the user can read any objects within that Realm (with a given partitionKey). Go through the [Task Tracker Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/preview/) which shows exactly how to read and write sync'd data.

Comment: I've gone through all of those tutorials - pls see my comment on Oblivion's answer below.

Comment: I read that comment and it's really quite different than this question; the question sounds like you're asking about *users* but in reality you're really asking about *other user data* and those are two entirely different things. It's important to note that while Realm has a SDK which provides really great platform to write apps, the **data** stored in MongoDB is not specifically "Realm Data" at all - it's MongoDB Atlas data that can be accessed via a variety of ways including REST calls. e.g. if your Realm data is synch'd then that synch'd data is in MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: I understand that, but the premise of my question was whether there is a native way to keep all Realm users synced to collection in the database, rather than being silo-ed to their own realm only.

Comment: Understood. Users and Realms are two separate things. Users don't have Realms, and Realms don't have users. More specifically a Realm *App* has users and a database collection. Any App user can access objects within that apps database. Using Rules, you can limit what users can access. In other words, a User is "silo-ed" to the App, not specific data within the App. So by default, if a local App connects to the sync server, any user of the app can access all objects in a collection. So, all app users will sync to a collection by default, which I think answers the question.

Comment: I guess it does answer the question, but I'm still not clear on the correct design pattern for having multiple Realm Apps all syncing to the same database collection, and retaining one giant user store in the database, containing all the users for the synced Realm Apps

Comment: Well, *"Multiple Realm Apps"* is a little vague, unless you truly mean 100% totally different apps having the same user base. e.g. I have an app that orders pizza that has users and another app that solves differential equations that has the same users. *IF* that's the case *any* app that connects to Realm using the same REALM_APP_ID will have the same set of users, and will synchronize with the same objects (which is all of them by default). You can optionally define which objects sync so that would provide a separation of pizza data and equation data (per my above example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I got a lot of useful info from the responses here, the solution I found was not mentioned.

The correct way to do this is still to do a manual copy of data from the Realm to the database via a triggered function.

Answer (score 0):

@jostell13 - REALM users are not ATLAS DATABASE USERS.

However, this does not mean that REALM users need their own collection for any new app.

When you create a realm app, you specify the ATLAS cluster it is associated with. There are multiple ways to do this - I'll go over two. SDK, Functions

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/examples/read-and-write-data/#read---write-data---swift-sdk

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/collections/#collections-are-live

The SDK provides LIVE collections, which is a really awesome capability. If LIVE collections, and things like real-time notifications, live updating objects, lazy-loading objects etc are not a requirement, you could also consider functions.

(Credit to @Jay for bringing up SDK > Functions)

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/

```
const plants = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("example").collection("plants");
const plant = await plants.findOne();
return JSON.stringify(plant);
```

Functions can be called from the REALM app, or you could even create things like HTTPS endpoints so you can interact with functions using simple HTTP requests. https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/endpoints/

The best part about functions is - DEPENDENCIES! You can literally use almost any npm module as a dependency for your functions! (There are some limitations, but this featureset will only be improving in the future)
https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/add-external-dependencies/

Comment: While this is an answer, I feel it's a tad incomplete. Realm offers SDK's that provide a very flexible interface for reading and writing data. While there are use cases for functions, by not using the SDK's you give up things like real-time notifications, live updating objects, lazy-loading objects etc. I would suggest leveraging the SDK's as your main go-to, and the implement functions for the edge cases. Just something to consider.

Comment: @Jay good catch - I will modify the answer to include SDK

Comment: Thanks all - I don't think I was perfectly clear in my question.  

I understand that Realm Users are NOT Atlas Database Users, but what I'm looking to do is going to involve syncing user data across Realms and into the Atlas Database.  For example, a user profile containing Name, Location, etc. will be accessed from our node.js server.  I have the Swift app running user account creation and sign-in, but i'll need access to that data from outside the Realm.

Comment: Interesting - I think I have something that could help - but swamped in meetings right now - I'll circle back in a bit.

Comment: To confirm, what you would like is - You want to have ONE realm app, with users and users custom data. And you'd like to be able to access some/part of that data from OUTSIDE the realm app? Like from an endpoint?

Comment: You have an app that handles creation/sign-in. And a node-js app that does some back-end stuff. You want to be able to access the same "custom user data" from both places, and not have to create two separate realm apps?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/link-identities/

Comment: Yes, that summarizes it I believe.  Unless they can both access the same Realm? My understanding of Realm's has mostly been that its a 1:1 relationship between realms and apps.  Ultimately I want all user data for all realms stored in a collection in my database, but was unsure if that was a custom thing I should write or if its supported in some way.